# How to build a graph of people where node connections are determined by name and age?

Tags: graphs

I was given the following question (please don't mind the programming language semantics, it's a language-agnostic question):

Given a list of `Person`s, and two arbitrary `Person`s out of that list, we need to find the minimum *nth-degree* relationship between them.

Here are the definitions of `Person` and a "relationship":

- A `Person` is defined as having 2 properties: `Name` and `Age`:

  ```
  class Person
  {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public int Age { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- A relationship between two `Person`s is defined as follows:

  1. Two `Person`s are considered to be in a *1st-degree* relationship if they have *either* the same name or the same age.
  2. Two `Person`s are considered to be in a *nth-degree* relationship if they have n people of 1st-degree connecting them.

Example input:

Given the following list of `Person`s:

```
persons = [{ Name = "John", Age = 60 }, { Name = "John", Age = 50 }, { Name = "Ted", Age = 50 }]
```

Then:

1. The two `John`s have a **1st degree** relationship (because they have the same name).
2. The second `John` and `Ted` have a **1st degree** relationship (because they have the same age).
3. Hence, the first `John` and `Ted` have a **2nd degree** relationship (because the second `John` connects them).

Now, I understand that it's a simple Dijkstra's algorithm question, but what I don't know is **how should we build the graph of `Person`s**?

I'm looking for an algorithm, but preferably code, that can build the graph in a time complexity which is better than $O(|V|^2)$.
If you think this question can be solved without building a graph (e.g., using BFS as mentioned in the comments), please let me know how can this be done, but I still want to know how to build the graph.

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question, but if you want to find the _distance_ between two vertices $v$ and $u$ (say distance $d$) and create an edge with label $d$ between $v$ and $u$, check out _power graphs_ and _transitive closures_.

Comment: @PålGD, if there are specifics you're not sure about my question, I'd be glad to clarify. I googled the terms you mentioned; I'm not sure how can they help in building the graph, but it seems that using them would be an overshoot for this interview question.

Comment: I'm not entirely comfortable with 2. of "relationship". I'd prefer *each is in 1st degree relationship with a person in n-1st degree relationship with the other*. (consider *Ike(5), Ike(6), Ike(7), Sue(6), Sue(7), Sue(8)*). What is the problem with the graph? *Adjacent* is equivalent to `either the same name or the same age`.

Comment: Do you want to answer the question for a single pair, or for all pairs? If all you want to find is the distance between a single pair of people, it seems that you can just do a single breadth-first search. An advantage of BFS is that you do not need to build the actual graph and leave the structure implicit. If you want a table of all pairs of distances, this output already has size $\Omega(|V|^2)$, so you might as well construct the entire graph.

Comment: @Discrete lizard, you actually touch two goals of my question: I want to (1) answer it for (any) single pair, but I also want to (2) learn how to build the graph. As for (1), I encourage you to make it an answer, because I'm not sure how that BFS solution would go. As for (2), I want to build the graph in a better time complexity than O(|V|^2).

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include all requirements in the question. As it stands you have requirements listed only in the comments.  We want questions to stand on their own, so people don't have to read the comments to understand what you are asking.  Also, it would help to clarify what kind of answer you are expecting when you ask "how should we build a graph".  Are you looking for a data structure?  for code?  What approaches have you considered, and what is the barrier for you?  It's not clear what level of an answer you are looking for.

Comment: @D.W, thanks, editted. Please let me know if you think there's something else missing.

Comment: FYI, we prefer not to use "EDIT:" -- see https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you want to build the graph of all people, with edges between each pair of people at degree 1.  Once you have this graph, it is straightforward to calculate the distance ("degree") between any two people using standard algorithms.

It's easy to build that graph in [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) format; or to store it implicitly and generate the adjacency lists on demand.

Store a hash table that maps from name to a list of all people with that name; and another hash table that maps from age to a list of all people with that age.  Now, given one person, you can use the hash tables to quickly find all other people who have a first-degree relationship with that person, i.e., who are adjacent in the graph.  This lets you build an adjacency list representation of the graph in $O(|V|+|E|)$ time, i.e., linear time rather than quadratic time.

Then, once you have this graph, you can compute distances using BFS in this graph.  Note that you can construct the graph on-the-fly as you execute the BFS algorithm; you don't need to build the entire graph in advance.

---

Footnote: I'm treating hash table lookups as $O(1)$ time.  This is a reasonable modelling assumption for practical work.  For theoretical work, you can ensure that lookups take $O(1)$ expected time if you use an appropriate hash function, which is nearly as good for most practical purposes.

Comment: I'm not clear about how should we get the path using both tables. I guess we should accommodate [Guido van Rossum's way](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/) for running with two graphs? but how? you can see my current clearly unsuccessful attempt [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VTHnHm). I'm also not clear about how can we generate the lists on demand while still keeping the complexity as suggested, but let me first understand the path calculation.

Comment: @HelterSkelter, That's not in the question.  You asked how to compute the graph, not how to find paths.  I notice now that you haven't defined what graph you want or what you mean by "the graph".  Since you know that you can use Dijkstra's to compute the distance between nodes, I assumed you wanted the graph with edges showing first-degree relationships.  But, OK, I edited my answer to add that information as well.  In the future, please make sure you include a careful specification of exactly what problem you want solved in the question from the start.

Comment: I asked about calculating the path in my last comment because *If* what you suggest is using two graphs (two hash tables), I don't know how to use Dijkstra for this. But I think this is not what you suggest; you have in mind a graph that is somehow built by combining the two hash tables? You assumed correctly what I mean by "the graph", but still, I'm not clear about how it should be built. It would be of much help if you could add an example displaying two example hash tables and the graph created based upon them.

Comment: @HelterSkelter please don't put important parts of your question into the comments.  As I've mentioned before, we want questions to be self-contained, so people don't have to read the comments to understand what you're asking.  Comments exist to help you improve your question, not to provide additional information or requirements not found in the question.  BFS is better than Dijkstra's algorithm, and I describe how to build the graph in my answer and how to use it to compute distances.  I'm not going to create an example - maybe you'll need to spend some time on this yourself.

Comment: Your solution, which I can see its cleverness, is not something I can Google with something like "BFS over two hash tables" or "... two graphs" or "adjacency list from two hash tables", so unfortunately, without a bit more info about how to build the adjacency list out of the two hash tables, I'm left in the dark. Thank you, though, I appreciate your time and efforts.

Comment: I think I succeeded in implementing a [DFS solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ckoFAe) according to your suggestion. I'll try and make a BFS implementation.

Comment: Here's the [BFS implementation](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XGb5Ka). I combined your solution and the implementation given [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-path-unweighted-graph/).

Answer (score 1):

Since your only parameters are name and age, you can make two lists, sort them, and then construct a graph using adjacency list:

$n \gets$ size of the set $\mathbf{persons}$;
$V \gets \{\ \}$;  // set of vertices
$\mathit{adj} \gets [\ ]$; // adjacency list
**for** $i = 1 \to n$  **do**

$\mathbf{persons}[i].\mathit{id} \gets i$;
$\mathit{adj}[i] \gets [\ ]$; //adjacency list of vertex $v_i$

**endfor**

$A \gets$ $\mathbf{persons}$ sorted by $\mathit{name}$;
$B \gets$ $\mathbf{persons}$ sorted by $\mathit{age}$;

**for** $i = 2 \to n$ **do**

**if** $A_i.\mathit{name} == A_{i-1}.\mathit{name}$ **then**
$Q \gets \{(i-1)\}$;
$j \gets i$;
**while** $A_j.\mathit{name} == A_{i-1}.\mathit{name}$ **do**
$Q \gets Q \cup \{j\}$;
$j \gets j+1$;
**endwhile**
add_clique($Q$); // this function runs in $|Q|$ and adds edges between all pairs in $Q$
$i \gets j$;
**endif**

**endfor**

**for** $i = 2 \to n$ **do**

**if** $B_i.\mathit{age} == B_{i-1}.\mathit{age}$ **then**
$Q \gets \{(i-1)\}$;
$j \gets i$;
**while** $B_j.\mathit{name} == B_{i-1}.\mathit{name}$ **do**
$Q \gets Q \cup \{j\}$;
$j \gets j+1$;
**endwhile**
add_clique($Q$);
$i \gets j$;
**endif**

**endfor**

The above operations take $O(n \log n)$ time to sort, and $O(n)$ time to create an adjacency list, which is less than $O(n^2)$ unless the number of edges are $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Can you explain how can the two sorted lists are then used to find the shortest path between two given persons? your solution is similar to D.W as it separates `persons` to two data structures, but what I still not get is how to use them to get the path.

Comment: This algorithm builds a graph in $O(n + n \log n)$ time, as you asked in the question. After the graph is obtained, Dijkstra's algorithm can be applied to find shortest path in the graph in $O(n + n \log n)$.

Comment: I may be blind, but where is The graph? I see two separate graphs (i.e., two separate lists whose items are connected by edges). Are they supposed to be merged somehow? if so, how?

Comment: @HelterSkelter I made some modifications to improve readability and introduced a variable named id to make it easier to identify the vertices.

Comment: Ah, I see it now, thank you!

Comment: @D.W. yes, I missed that point. But if there are $O(n^2)$ edges, then how can one build a graph in less than $O(n^2)$?

Comment: @padawan you can't!  That's the point.  The best you can do is $O(n+m)$, where $n$ is the number of vertices and $m$ is the number of edges.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no other constraints, it's easy to represent the graph using an adjacency matrix. You can construct a matrix where an entry `A[3,2]` will represent the relationship between `persons[3]` and `persons[2]`. So if you want to represent the edge between two "John"s, your entry `A[0,1]` would be equal to `1`. You can iterate through each of the elements of `persons` and fill the matrix this way. Note that this makes adding a vertex $O(|V|^2)$.

Comment: shouldn't there be a better solution than O(|V|^2)?

Comment: @HelterSkelter not with a representation using $\Theta(|V|^2)$ space.

Comment: *this makes adding a vertex $O(|V|^2)$* I don't see that - adding *all* vertices should take that long.

Comment: @greybeard, sure, that's what I was implying. D.W. answer does that, but unfortunately I can't figure how to build the adjacency list out of the two hash tables it suggests. It would be great if you can shed some light on it.

Comment: @greybeard, [this is as far as I've got](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GVLRh6). I tried to accommodate [Guido van Rossum's algorithm](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/) for iterating two hash tables instead of one, so that instead of just iterating upon `graph` as he does, we need to have an outer `graphByName` and an inner `graphByAge`. It doesn't work, and I don't know how to fix it, and it all boils down to me not understanding how to build the adjacency list out of the two hash tables. Any additional help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This will be more of a programming/coding companion to [D.W.'s answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/130711/19966) than a self-contained answer to *how should we build the graph of `Person`s?*

You seem to have narrow concept of *graph* and *building a/the graph* that I don't seem to share.

I see *nodes*: Persons and *edges*: equality of one of a specified set of properties of `Person` - that's my *graph*, even before I think of *representation*.

Different algorithms on graphs need different operations supported - examples:

- predicate *adjacent*: given two nodes, are they?
  this can be answered for two nodes in the presentation presented in the question
- iterating ("outgoing", if directed) *edges of a node*
  as edges in this problem don't carry information, this is equivalent to *iterating directly connected node* - I'd skip modelling edges and support the latter.
  *How* depends on implementation/run-time environment. Alienated by C#, I have to consult docs.microsoft.com to find `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Person>` should fit the bill.
  If I assigned to every `Person` a separate collection of its namesakes and peers, that is bound to require $\Theta(n^2)$ space - not following this train of thought.
  I can build collections of namesakes and collections of peers as I add `Person`s to the graph (which is what I take D.W. to suggest). To get suitable enumerators *without explicitly specifying additional parameters*, a C# `Person`/`Node` should  be a class *nested* in `Graph`. The `IEnumerable<Person>` implementation would `yield return` each namesake and each peer, skipping the object which was used to invoke it.

Comment: `concept of … to share` consider to elaborate in the question!

Comment: Thank you. Do you have an idea on how to build the adjacency list out of the two hash tables D.W suggested?

Comment: I don't see a need for an adjacency list. If I wanted it and had the `IEnumerable<Person>` from above answer, I'd get `Person`s from it one by one and add them to a list. What *do* you want an adjacency list for?

Comment: I'm referring it because that's what D.W suggested: "It's easy to build that graph in adjacency list format". But I don't get *how* it should be built. BTW, if it'd be better for you, I can convert my C# to python.

Comment: `[an adjacency list is] what D.W suggested` not exactly: he mentioned it as one possibility, to go on and sketch how to `store it implicitly and generate the [node] adjacency lists on demand.` using two `dict`s (Python naming). Much the same as sketched above for `IEnumarable`s/[generator iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-iterator): for any given person, take the union of its namesakes and peers and take out the person itself. For the *graph adjacency list*, repeat for all persons.